# Cursor displaying on the header in ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have a fixed header in hybrid ios app. When focus on text box and scroll the screen, textbox is behind the header but cursor is showing at top of the header in ios.
Tried through setting color of caret in textbox, it is working in android but by checking in ios build, it again showing its default blue color.
Is there any way to change color of caret in textbox in ios in hybrid apps.

Comment: Can you please post your code in https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and it is from Webkit and Apple's WKWebview.

You can keep tracking the official issues here for a workaround:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12992

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13013